# Content Size Filter disregards TMP_Text in child object

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have a Horizontal Layout Group with 3 child objects with Image components: Like, Download, Favorite, each of these objects has a child object with a TMP_Text component and a Content Size FIlter to make the object grow in width when text is entered, I want to change the width of the text to change the size of its parent element (Like, Download or Favorite) and move the Horizontal Layout Group, I added a Content Size Filter to Like, but the size of Like did not take into account the text size of the child object.

Hierarchy

[image]

Characteristics

[image]

After i add Content Size Filter to Like it becomes narrow and disregards Child object
[image]

Comment: you could divide the area in 3, inside each left align the picture, right aline the text?  or even center both next to each other with the text auto growing to accomodate..

Comment: you could also just have all 6 (3 images + 3 texts) nested under the horizontal layout group on the same level - or have 3 additional wrappers using a contentsizeFitter + horizontal layout group and have the image and text nested on the same level below that one - in general if you ant to set a certain size to things that are not really driven by content (the images e.g.) you can use a `LayoutElement` and adjust its `PreferredWidth` and `MinWidth`

Comment: I don't want to make 6 objects, because each text should be next to its Like Download Favorite object and should resize it when characters are added or removed so that they move in horizontal layout, but the problem is that Content Size Filter on Like Download Favorite objects doesn't increase with the text